# get the string[] in android from list

Tags: java, android, string, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I have to develop an one android application.

Here i have to get the list of items and set that list of item value in android spinner.

So i have using following code:

```
if (getIntent().getExtras() !=null) {
    retailerNamesList = (ArrayList<RetailerNames>) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("RetailerName");

    for (int i=0;i<retailerNamesList.size();i++) {}

    mRetailerNameAdapter = new RetailerNamesAdapter(WatchList.this,retailerNamesList);
    retailerlist.setAdapter(mRetailerNameAdapter);
}
```

Here i get the list of arraylist values in that spinner.but i have to split these values and set it in android spinner.please help me.how can i do ???

**EDIT:**

In the above code am getting the output like:

**[com.example.RetailerNames@41216470]**

But i need to get the output like:

String[] period_timings={"0-2 days","Within a Week","Within a Month"};

That list have to split and get the values in string[].How can i write the code for these ??? please provide me solution for these ???

Comment: use this `retailerNamesList.get(i)`.

Comment: Do you want to get a String[] from an ArrayList of RetailerNames ?

Comment: @blackbelt yes i have to get the String[] from that  ArrayList of RetailerName.What's the solution for these ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 for (int i=0;i<retailerNamesList.size();i++){
     retailerNamesList.get(i);
 }
```

or if you really have to create an array of it then

```
 final int nameListSize = retailerNamesList.size();
 String []names = new String[nameListSize];
 for (int i=0;i<nameListSize ;i++){
     names[i] = retailerNamesList.get(i);
 }
 // use the string array names to set wherever u need.
```

Comment: i have using below code means am getting the o/p like:06-25 10:21:55.346: I/System.out(1141): [Ljava.lang.String;@4118f598
...please provide me solution for my updated question. final int nameListSize = retailerNamesList.size();
 String []names = new String[nameListSize];

Comment: @user2218667 Implement a toString() method in your RetilerNames class. You can autogenerate that method using eclipse: right click on your class->Source->Generate toString(). The string you return from that method, will be used for printing the object.

Comment: I got the output.Thanks for your valuable answer.here i have learned tostring autogenerate method.Thank you so much.